# How do you run some code after an element is added to ngFor in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have a function in my component that adds an element to an array which is displayed by *ngFor in the view.

I wish to target the added element by an id and scroll to it after adding it to the array. Problem is this code runs before the element is added to the view.

How would I workaround this in Angular 2+?

Comment: Is this only about the initial add or also if you add items to the array you use `*ngFor` on?

Comment: Its for when you add items to the array I use `*ngFor` on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom directive that does the notification:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[afterAdd]')
class MyDirective {
  @Output() added:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.added.next(null);
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" afterAdd (added)="doSomething(item)">
```

this way `doSomething()` on the parent component will be called for each item added by `*ngFor` (also for the initial add of all items in the array)

alternatively you can also ensure the item was added to the DOM like

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

...
this.items.push(newItem);
this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // sync
// here the item was added to the DOM already
```

Comment: Good solution. However, I don't want to run this on an initial add of all items. I want to scroll down to the last item only if one is added to the already existing list.

Comment: Great! your 2nd approach was useful, worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear :)